# Neural network learning from it's own experience

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I'm trying to make a blackjack game and connecting neural network to it. I'm giving all possible combinations of a game and neural network should say what to do (hit, stand, double, split). I'm picking an answer with roulette wheel selection and when neural network wins with his choice ( for example HIT ) I'm adding a small number to this output's target and when he looses I'm subtract a small number and teaching it with backpropagation learning. But this method doesn't seem to work, any solutions?

Comment: Why would you subtract the teaching....anyway...
Normal mind never loses  the memory until is's hit in the head :)

Comment: Where does the roulette wheel come in?  Shouldn't the feedback be based on the win/loss result when it really plays a hand?

Comment: look at reinforcement learning